# trigger click event from div instead of link

Tags: jquery

I want to clear the alert without using the link below (class="remove") but when the user clicks anywhere in say a div on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".remove").click(function(){
$("#errprompt").remove();
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border-style:solid;">
<p><a class="remove" href="#">Clear Alerts</a></p>
<span id="errprompt" class="errprompt" name="firstname">* Please enter something</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("div").click(function(){
$("#errprompt").remove();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery.onClick()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on a div object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div.clickable").click(function(){
            $("#errprompt").remove();
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border-style:solid;" class="clickable">
    <p><a class="remove" href="#">Clear Alerts</a></p>
    <span id="errprompt" class="errprompt" name="firstname">* Please enter something</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if it answer your question, let me know.

Comment: this works for the example I gave however when I plug this solution into my actual code it doesn't work. 
however since you came up with a solution I'm happy to mark this as such.

Comment: Ahah, sorry for you if it does not resolve your issue at the end. It might come from a lots of different thing ... the easiest way I thing would be to spend some time in your web console and display some console.log() to see what is happenning. If you want to suggest a more complexe exemple, feel free I can give a look for you ;)